# Why there is no SelectorT?

Tags: c++-winrt, cppwinrt

I am trying to implement a custom control (I call it DataGrid) , which I choose to derive from `Selector`. In cppwinrt , I write some like this

```cpp
struct DataGrid : SelectorT<DataGrid>
{
}
```

This code does not compile. In fact , there is no such a struct called `SelectorT` in any of the shipped Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.h files. I've checked the winmd file shipped with the SDK (19041) , found that `Selector` is `Composable` (has the `ComposableAttribute` attribute), so, `SelectorT` should have been generated , what I've missed ? Many thanks!

Comment: It seems that ```Selector``` has no any constructors declared (in the winmd). That means there is no any factories. For the in-box control , such as ```ListBox``` (which derived from ```Selector```) , I believe it use the constructor directly. I.E. the case of both authoring and consuming in the same compilation unit in the doc. So I believe that I can't derive from ```Selector``` from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `SelectorT` because `Selector` can not be subclassed. The `TypenameT` class templates in the consuming projection are not provided for convenience, they exist to provide user-defined subclasses of Xaml types that support it. This allows the user to define their own implementations of *overrideable* methods. (Think of it as similar to C++ virtual functions, but in a complicated COM aggregation way)

The docs don't appear to spell out in clear words which classes can be subclassed, and which ones can't. You can deduce this, though, from the presence of `ComposableAttribute` on the type, as in [FrameworkElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.onapplytemplate?view=winui-3.0).